# Show div on radio button check

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, show-hide

I would like to hide a div until the leased radio button is selected. This div contains input fields only relative to the leased radio selection, so hiding them when the owned radio button is selected is preferred. However, the code I have is not working.

HTML

```
<div id="surv_radio4">
    <p>
        Merchant Site Property is
    </p>
    <input type="radio" id="owned" value="owned" name="merchant_property"/>
    <label for="owned">Owned</label>
    <input type="radio" id="leased" value="leased" name="merchant_property"/>
    <label for="leased">Leased</label>
</div>
<div id="surv_5">
    <label for="landlord_name" class="test">Landlord Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="landlord_name" placeholder="Landlord Name"/>
    <label for="landlord_phone">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="landlord_phone" placeholder="XXX-XXX-XXXX"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#surv_5 {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready.(function() {
    $("input[name$='merchant_property']").click(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == 'leased') {
            $("#surv_5").show();
        } else if (value == 'owned') {
            $("#surv_5").hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: the code I have is not working...any suggestions for a solution?

Comment: change the else to a else if maybe

Comment: And remove the `.` between `ready` and `(function() { ` in the first line

Comment: NB: Use the debugging tools provided in all modern web browsers (instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) for Google Chrome) - that way you can view any error messages and attempt to fix yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your document.ready function has a syntax error (extra period):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/tW3D5/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input[name$='merchant_property']").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();    
    if (value == 'leased') {        
        $("#surv_5").show();
    } else {
        $("#surv_5").hide();
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Fta29/1)**

Answer (score 0):

On your original code, you also had an error on your else statement.. **[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RLAN3/2/)**

Relevant bits below:

```
if (value == 'leased') {
  $("#surv_5").show();
} else if(value == 'owned'){
  $("#surv_5").hide();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Too late, looks like @Hiral has an answer for you....